# Fill Content of V-Container to screen

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a page that is unnecessatily scrollable by a few pixel. I want to display the page with screen height so that everything is displayed without the option to scroll.

Here is what the page looks like

[Page Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01coG.png)

Here is the code:

```
`<template>
    <v-container class="grow d-flex flex-column flex-nowrap">
        <v-row class="mr-3">
            <v-col>
                <p class="global--header1 my-6">
                    Header
                </p>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row class="mr-3">
            <v-col md="9">
                <v-card>
                    <div>
                        <video-player>
                        </video-player>
                    </div>
                    <v-card-text>
                       Video Title
                    </v-card-text>
                    <v-card-text>
                        Video Text
                    </v-card-text>
                    <div class="text-right mx-auto">
                        <v-btn  class="tp-intro--button"
                                @click="buttonFunction()">
                            Button Function
                        </v-btn>
                    </div>
                </v-card>
            </v-col>
            <v-col md="3">
                <v-card class="global--card-border">
                    <v-img fluid-grow />
                </v-card>
                <v-card class="global--card-border mt-6">
                    <v-row no-gutters align="center">
                        <v-card flat>
                            1
                        </v-card>
                        <v-col>
                            <p>
                                Text
                            </p>
                            <p>
                               Text
                            </p>
                        </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                </v-card>
                <v-card>
                    <v-row no-gutters align="center">
                        <v-col>
                            <p>
                                Text
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Text
                            </p>
                        </v-col>
                        <v-card flat>
                            2
                        </v-card>
                    </v-row>
                </v-card>
                <v-card>
                    <v-row no-gutters align="center">
                        <v-card flat>
                            3
                        </v-card>
                        <v-col>
                            <p>
                                Text
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Text
                            </p>
                        </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                </v-card>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>`
```

I tried setting the container height to 100vh and making it display: flex but that didn't work.

Comment: setting `min-height: 100vh` and `max-height: 100vh` with `height: 100vh` may help.

Comment: Would be easy to help if you make a reproducible scenario from example play.vuetifyjs.com